# file path in variable from user input

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create script where user will give path to some file, and script will check if file exists and do some stuff...
I've wrote this code:

```
read -p "Enter path: " $path

#check if path is not empty string
if [ -z $path ]
then
  echo "path is empty string"
  exit
fi
#check if file exist
if [ ! -f $path ] 
then
  echo "file doesnt exists"
fi
```

my problem is with secound condition - if I change `$path` with some string everything is OK, but when I enter path via variable it is always "file doesnt exists" I was trying with

```
if [ ! -f `$path` ]
```

but if file doesnt have execute permission result is fail too. Can someone help me fix above code? :)

**EDIT** sorry, I meant `-z` and `-f` not  double `-z` condition

Comment: You're using the `-z` test twice, you might want `-e` to check if the file exists in the second test condition?

Comment: yeah, `-e` was correct, I was trying with `-f` but if file was without execute permission i get error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the backticks:

```
`command`
```

are used to run a command and substitute its output streams (standard and error) as a result, which is why the test fails when you supply a file without execute permissions.

**How to fix this**

Use

```
if [ -f "$path" ]
```

The double quotes are to protect against word splitting (in case the contains spaces) and against globbing (in case the path contains wildcard characters like `*` or `?`)

Even better, since the path may be to a directory, simply check for the existence of the path with `-e`:

```
if [ -e "$path" ]
```